# Adding Name column and assigning 5 session ID's to each name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called customers -DDL below

```
CREATE TABLE customers
  (
    sessionID  INT
   ,customerID VARCHAR(100)
  );

INSERT INTO customer
VALUES
  (10435, 'RTE')
 ,(2312, 'RTE')
 ,(2980, 'RTE')
 ,(1365, 'RTE')
 ,(1106, 'RTE')
 ,(9682, 'RTE')
 ,(5779, 'RTE')
 ,(3609, 'GTE')
 ,(2881, 'GTE')
 ,(4197, 'GTE')
 ,(2905, 'GTE')
 ,(6390, 'GTE')
 ,(4514, 'GTE')
 ,(7617, 'GTE')
 ,(7138, 'GTE')
 ,(5927, 'GTE')
 ,(397, 'GTE')
 ,(5949, 'LOA')
 ,(4324, 'LOA')
 ,(7399, 'LOA')
 ,(1459, 'LOA')
 ,(2016, 'LOA')
 ,(6650, 'LOA')
 ,(7562, 'LOA')
 ,(9057, 'nma')
 ,(3066, 'nma')
 ,(9184, 'nma')
 ,(8042, 'nma')
 ,(2348, 'nma')
 ,(9755, 'nma')
 ,(6770, 'nma')
 ,(661, 'nma')
 ,(4084, 'nma')
 ,(4991, 'nma')
 ,(8822, 'nma')
 ,(3632, 'nma')
 ,(2296, 'nma');
```

Now I have a stored procedure to extract the top 20 session ID's on a day to day basis in the format of HTML table for mailing purposes

```
 SELECT
  @Report1WeeklyBody1 =
(
  SELECT
    TOP 20
    TD = sessionID
   ,TD = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), customerid)
   ,TD = @URL + sessionID
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT
        sessionID
       ,customerID
      FROM
        customers
      WHERE
        CONVERT(DATETIME, dateofevent, 111) BETWEEN DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), '04:00:00:001') AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, -1, GETDATE()), '03:59:59:999')
      GROUP BY
        sessionID
       ,customerid
    ) AS A
  ORDER BY
    NEWID()
  FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS
);
```

Now I have to modify the above stored procedure to  add a new column name and assign 5 different session ID's each to the following names:

> Max, Allen, Amy, Josh, Suzier

so that the entire HTML table with the 25 sessions ID's assigned to the five names can be sent daily

Can some one please help with the same.

I am using SQL server 2017

Comment: [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some points on making your question easier to answer.

Comment: It sounds like you want to cross-apply the recipients into your detail data. If that is the case then cross apply would work.

Comment: Ross ,Can you please expand on your inputs...I am not understanding how cross apply would help me in my stored procedure

Comment: Can you show the desired output based on your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move the top clause to the inner select and change the number of rows to be 25. Then add a new column in the inner select to show the row number. In the outer select check the row number and depending on the range (1..5, 6..10, etc.) return different person.

At the end, your select statement should look something like this:

```
SELECT
  @Report1WeeklyBody1 =
(
  SELECT
    TD = sessionID
   ,TD = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), customerid)
   ,TD = @URL + sessionID
   ,TD = case when RowNo <= 5 then 'Max'
            when RowNo <= 10 then 'Allen'
            when RowNo <= 15 then 'Amy'
            when RowNo <= 20 then 'Josh'
            when RowNo <= 25 then 'Suzier' end
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT TOP 25
        sessionID
       ,customerID
       , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by newid()) as RowNo
      FROM
        @customers
      WHERE
        CONVERT(DATETIME, dateofevent, 111) BETWEEN DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), '04:00:00:001') AND DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, -1, GETDATE()), '03:59:59:999')
      GROUP BY
        sessionID
       ,customerid
    ) AS A
  ORDER BY
    NEWID()
  FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS
);
```